# Travis CI - Mono: 5.4.0.201

Tags: travis-ci

I need to be using version 5.4.0.201 of mono in order for netstandard to work correctly (as per: https://github.com/cake-build/cake/issues/2063)

In my travis.yml I tried specifying: `mono: 5.4.0.201` however travis doesn't seem to recognise that as a valid mono version. What is the best / easiest way (if any) to overcome this? This is an open source project https://travis-ci.org/GitTools/GitVersion/jobs/362727450

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Travis yml mono segment to

```
mono:
  - 5.4.1
  - latest
```

Comment: No joy. 5.4.1 results in a nasty error at the cake comile script step: https://travis-ci.org/GitTools/GitVersion/jobs/362785438#L1946
- latest has the original error re netstandard.

Comment: Hmm that's no good, indicates internal mono issue, and mono: 5.2.0 gives the netstandard issue?

Comment: Yup, `5.2.0` and `latest` both result in netstandard issue: https://travis-ci.org/GitTools/GitVersion/jobs/362811463#L1945

5.4.0 and 5.4.1 both result in weird mono error: https://travis-ci.org/GitTools/GitVersion/jobs/362813436#L1948

Comment: I'm using Mono 5.4.1.7 here without issue on Ubuntu. This needs some new investigation, please raise an new issue in the Cake GitHub repository.